# Wordpress Multisite: Warning: An existing WordPress network was detected

Tags: php, wordpress

I had enabled the multi-site function on wordpress, after which I had to remove it.
now i'm trying again to get this feature back. But I can't do it

I already deleted the mysql tables (all the necessary ones), changed the wp_config.php and .htaccess

```
Warning: An existing WordPress network was detected
```

Comment: Have you followed this guide? https://zanca.it/blog/2017/08/02/warning-an-existing-wordpress-network-was-detected/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your .htaccess and wp-config.php file, i think that code remains there which you had pasted it while making the multisite network.
 If not then try to install the fresh wordpress site and then make the site multistore by editing the new .htaccess and wp-config.php file....thanks